# Poloniex API error using postman

Tags: postman, poloniex

1. Step1-Body
   [image]
2. Step2-Pre-req script to apply HMACSHA512.
   [image]
3. Step3-Headers for the POST Request. The hmacd in Step2 is applied to the request as header.
   [image]
   I am facing a 403 Forbidden
   {
   "error": "Invalid API key/secret pair."
   }
   as above.
   Any suggestions to get the hit the right path is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to base64 stringify it after using HMAC-SHA512?

Comment: Is it saving the environment variable as you expect it too?

Comment: Hey Danny, without base64 stringify, it represents itself as [Object Object] in http headers. Environment Variable is translating as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
pm.environment.set("hmacd", hashInBase64);
```

You should use

```
var hashInHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
pm.environment.set("hmacd", hashInHex);
```

As Poloniex uses Hex encoding instead of Base64 encoding for the signature.

Comment: Let me know how it goes.